# Search content for shortcodes and get parameters

Tags: filters, shortcode, content

In content I can have multiple shortcodes like `[book id="1"] [book id="14" page="243"]`

Is there any help method with which I can search the content for that shortcode and get its parameters? I need to get IDs so I can call WP_Query and append the Custom Post Types titles at the end.

```
function filter_books( $content ) {

// get all shortcodes IDs and other parameters if they exists
...

return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_books', 15 );
```

I tried using following code but var_dump($matches) is empty and if it would work I am not sure how would I get parameters (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205537/wordpress-shortcode-filtering-the-content-modifies-all-posts-in-a-list)

```
  $shortcode = 'book';
  preg_match('/\['.$shortcode.'\]/s', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: you can remove the shortcode and then recreate the same to catch arguments : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/

Comment: I suggest looking at how WordPress parses Shortcodes internally, starting with [`get_shortcode_regex`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex), all of the functions you'd need are in core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me

```
  $shortcode = 'book';
  $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

  // if shortcode 'book' exists
  if ( preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
    && array_key_exists( 2, $matches )
    && in_array( $shortcode, $matches[2] ) )  {
   $shortcode_atts = array_keys($matches[2], $shortcode);

 // if shortcode has attributes
 if (!empty($shortcode_atts)) {
  foreach($shortcode_atts as $att) {
    preg_match('/id="(\d+)"/', $matches[3][$att], $book_id);

    // fill the id into main array
    $book_ids[] = $book_id[1];
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a much simpler way to achieve this.  When the content is parsed by WP, it executes the shortcodes it finds in the content.  As of WP 4.7 a new filter, [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/) is triggered when a shortcode is replaced by its content.  This is really useful to add additional content to the shortcode output based on the attributes found,

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag','add_my_script',10,3);
function enqueue_my_script($output, $tag, $attr){
  if('aShortcode' != $tag){ //make sure it is the right shortcode
    return $output;
  }
  if(!isset($attr['id'])){ //you can even check for specific attributes
    return $output;
  }
  $output.='<script> ... </script>';
  return $output;
}
```

alternatively, if you need to put something into the footer of your page, you could hook onto the [wp_footer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) action within the above function  either an an [anonymous function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/#more-information) or to fire another function in your file.